# Use Cython Librairy from Matlab

Tags: matlab, cython

I am doing a code on matlab and I use pyenv to load python scripts. However I also would want to load Cython functions referencing a C script (I have pyx and pxd files).

Someone has any idea to bypass the need to reimplement the script from C to Matlab by reusing what was done in Cython?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: If you want to use C, why don't you use a mex function? Why put Cython in between?

Comment: Either what Daniel said, or directly using [`calllib`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/calllib.html). You can also run Python functions from within MATLAB, but I would prefer to skip the intermediate layers.

Comment: I will use a mex function, it was just to know if I could bypass recoding what I did in Cython in Matlab because it is pretty long.